# Fetching data of a sub Object with hibernate 3 criteria and complex projections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

i have two entities (ManyToOne relation)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = USER")
public class User  {
........
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "default_profile")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Profile default_profile;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROFILE")
public class Profile extends AbstractDBModel {
....

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "default_profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User>       user;
```

}

Using my methode service the User informations are well retrieved, but not for Profile information
here is my service :

```
    List<User> users;
    SearchResult<User> result = new SearchResult<>();
    try {
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class);
        DetachedCriteria profileCrit = criteria.createCriteria("default_profile");

        String login = search.getAttributeByCode("login");
        String firstName = search.getAttributeByCode("first_name");
        String lastName = search.getAttributeByCode("last_name");
        String status = search.getAttributeByCode("status");
        String type = search.getAttributeByCode("type");

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(login))
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("login", login));
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(firstName))
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("first_name", firstName));
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(lastName))
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("last_name", lastName));
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(status))
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", status));
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(type))
            profileCrit.add(Restrictions.gt("type",type));

        result.setTotalRecords(userDalService.getCountFromCriteria(criteria));

        if (search.getPageNumber() >= 0 && search.getPageSize() > 0) {
            ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
            projList.add(Projections.property("login"), "login");
            projList.add(Projections.property("first_name"), "first_name");
            projList.add(Projections.property("last_name"), "last_name");
            projList.add(Projections.property("status"), "status");
            projList.add(Projections.property("UserId"), "UserId");
            //projList.add(Projections.property("default_profile.type"), "type");
            //projList.add(Projections.property("default_profile.label"), "label");

            criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
            criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(User.class));
            users = userDalService.searchByCriteriaPaginated(criteria, search.getPageNumber(),
                    search.getPageSize());
            result.setResults(users);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

I think entities association is not well made that's why profile information are not retrieved.

Comment: "profile information are not retrieved" - can you elaborate? How do you determine that profiles are not retrieved? Do the users have profiles anyway? Is `default_profile` null when you load the users? Also why are you using individual field projections here instead of loading entire entities? As per your code there's no projection for the profile.

Comment: Yes all users have a profile in my DB, but in users list default_profile is null.i just test individual field projection.

Comment: what happens if you do not invoke the instructions `criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
            criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(User.class));` ?